# Error when compiling simple SPARC ASM math code

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, sparc

Writing SPARC asm code to evaluate a hardcoded statement, but I'm getting an error I don't understand.  I've searched all over, and while it seems to come up a lot in some bug reports out there, there's no real clues that I've found for programmers.  Yes, it is homework, and yes, I'm not finished, and yes I have branch delays all over the place.  I'll get to them on my own, but I need to know what the error is.  This error's not telling me anything useful, and the books I have aren't any good for it either.

I'm really new at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  1 /*Justin Reeves*/
  2 /*max{x^3-14x^2+56x-64} from [-2,8]*/
  3 /*for (x = lwr, x <= upr, x++) */
  4 define(lwr_b, -2)       !lower bound
  5 define(upr_b, 8)        !upper bound
  6 define(x_r, %l0)        !x
  7 define(sum_r, %l1)      !sum, each pass of loop may update
  8 define(max_r, %l2)      !max, cmp to sum, store in max if larger
  9
 10     .global main
 11 main:
 12     save    %sp, -64, %sp
 13
 14     ba      loop_test
 15     mov     lwr_b,  x_r     /*init x_r = -2 */
 16
 17 loop_test:
 18     cmp     x_r,    upr_b
 19     ble     sum_loop
 20     nop
 21 /*then x > upr_b and the max has been found*/
 22 /*odd spot for it...but this is the end of the program*/
 23
 24
 25 sum_loop: ! starting backwards to give us an intial nonzero constant sum
 26     mov     -64,    sum_r   /* sum = -64 */
 27
 28     mov     x_r,    %o0     /*56x*/
 29     mov     56,     %o0
 30     clr     %o2
 31     call    .mul            /*AFAIK 56x should now be in %o0*/
 32     nop
 33     add     sum_r,  %o0,    sum_r   /* sum = 56x-64 */
 34
 35     mov     x_r,    %o0     /* 14x^2 */
 36     mov     x_r,    %o1
 37     mov     -14,    %o2
 38     call    .mul
 39     nop
 40     add     sum_r,  %o0,    sum_r   /* sum = -14x^2+56x-64 */
 41
 42     mov     x_r,    %o0
 43     mov     x_r,    %o1
 44     mov     x_r,    %o2
 45     call    .mul
 46     nop
 47     add     sum_r,  %o0,    sum_r   /*sum = x^3-14x^2+56x-64 */
 48
 49     add     x_r,    1,      x_r     /* x++ */
 50     cmp     sum_r,  max_r
 51     bge     collect_lrg             /*branches if sum > max*/
 52     nop
 53
 54 collect_lrg:
 55     mov     sum_r,  max_r
 56     ba      loop_test
 57
 58     mov     1,      %g1     /*exit request*/
 59     ta      0               /*trap to system*/
```

---

then when I try to define the macros and compile I get:

cs32107@matrix:~$ m4 polynomialv2.m > polynomial.s
cs32107@matrix:~$ gcc -g polynomial.s -o polynomial
ld: fatal: relocation error: R_SPARC_32: file /var/tmp//ccVOrnx2.o: symbol : offset 0xfb5d11dd is non-aligned
ld: fatal: relocation error: R_SPARC_32: file /var/tmp//ccVOrnx2.o: symbol : offset 0xfb5d120f is non-aligned
ld: fatal: relocation error: R_SPARC_32: file /var/tmp//ccVOrnx2.o: symbol : offset 0xfb5d1215 is non-aligned
ld: fatal: relocation error: R_SPARC_32: file /var/tmp//ccVOrnx2.o: symbol : offset 0xfb5d1219 is non-aligned
ld: fatal: relocation error: R_SPARC_32: file /var/tmp//ccVOrnx2.o: symbol : offset 0xfb5d121d is non-aligned
ld: fatal: relocation error: R_SPARC_32: file /var/tmp//ccVOrnx2.o: symbol : offset 0xfb5d1266 is non-aligned
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
cs32107@matrix:~$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug in the assembler causes debugging code to add unaligned data access. Don't use -g but perhaps -gstabs if you need debugging information. There maybe an update for gas that fixes the problem too.

Comment: Others are now telling me it compiles fine on their machines. It's a campus machine so I can't do anything like installing or updating new packages.  I a small ssh account.

I am most perplexed, and do require the gdb output.

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is to verify whether it does compile without the -g option, that way you'll at least be sure the assembler is the problem (it should be the assembler adding debugging code, because your code doesn't have any symbol declarations, so it can't have the unaligned symbols the linker complains about and this was a known bug around 2005). Then either compile the file on others' machines or find out what else is different between your and their machine.